# How to Replace Format date when convert to csv C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I have problem when convert data to csv, especially format date "dd-MM-yyyy".

```
public void Export_CSV(DataTable dt, string FileName, string Separator, string Path)
{
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + Path + "/" + FileName + ".csv");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                      Select(column => column.ColumnName).
                                      ToArray();
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string[] fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).
                                        ToArray();
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
    }

    File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString());
}
```

The result, format date is not constant. It should be like "dd-MM-yyyy"

[image]

Comment: Seems like US date format at work in Excel (it tries to interpret it as MM-dd-yyyy, and either succeeds or fails depending on whether first number is greater than 12). You can check CSV file in notepad and make sure the dates are just fine in there. If you are fine with dates being stored as text in Excel, you can prepend the date value with one single quote character. Otherwise, you'll have to look into why you use dd-MM-yyyy while your excel uses MM-dd-yyyy.

Comment: How is the date stored in the data source? Is the field a DateTime field or a string (varchar etc) field? What is the difference between the data that is converted correctly and the data that isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the default DateTimeFormat of the CurrentInfo.CurrentCulture and so your forcing the default DateTime format that ToString will spit out.

I belive by default that the .ToString() will produce d/MM/yyyy which correlates to the ShortString format.

Try adding the following to you code before the dates are output.

```
CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone(); 
culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

To revert back to what you what was set, just add in some code to store the original value first then reset at end of method

```
CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone(); 
var originalShortDatePattern = culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
...
Your code
...
culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = originalShortDatePattern ;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

Worth a try